# Static Input Dialog with JDialog

Tags: java, swing, static, while-loop, jdialog

I made this sample:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JDialogTest extends JDialog implements ActionListener{
    private boolean actionPerformed;
    private JButton okButton;
    private JTextField textField;

    private JDialogTest(String title, JFrame frame){
        super(frame, title, true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        init();
    }

    public static String getInput(String title, JFrame frame){
        JDialogTest input = new JDialogTest(title, frame);
        input.setVisible(true);

        while(true){
            if(input.actionPerformed){
                input.setVisible(false);
                String text = input.textField.getText();
                return text;
            }
        }
    }

    private void init(){

        textField = new JTextField();
        okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(this);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));

        add(textField);
        add(okButton);
        pack();     
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("click");
        actionPerformed = true;     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(JDialogTest.getInput("Test", null));
    }



}
```

I create new Dialog via a static method witch returns a string.
But the while-loop witch should detect if the button was pressed won't get started!
I know about JOptionPanes but I don't want to use them. I tried using a JFrame instead but it doesn't work if I try to init the Dialog inside of another JFrame/JDialog (it doesn't render).

Comment: `while(true)` this is gonna to freeze your gui. What are you trying to achieve? You add an action listener to the component and it's fire when the event happen, you don't have to use a boolean flag!. BTW it's certainly not necesary to extends `JDialog`

Comment: This goes against all precepts of Swing and event driven programming in general. Because your program is event-driven, you don't need to and shouldn't try to circumvent the event-driven mechanism with a `while (true)` loop. What you want in fact to use is a ***modal*** dialog, such as can be achieved with either a JOptionPane or a modal JDialog.

Comment: I have to use the Boolean because the getInput() method needs to know when the button is clicked -> when it should return the text from the textField

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for the code that illustrates what you are trying to do. I was able to compile it but not able to run it as there is no `main()` method. Can you please provide a complete example that we can compile *and* run so that we can see for ourselves what you are trying to do?

Comment: You `addActionListener` to the button, so when the button is clicked, then the event is gonna to be fire!

Comment: As I said I don't want to use JOptionPanes and what do  you exactly mean by modal JDialog?

Comment: @VoidCatz As Hovercraft explained, you are completely circumventing the event driven system that Swing provides for you. Can you explain in words what you are trying to accomplish with this code? In other words, what exactly do you expect the user to do and what should the response be from the app?

Comment: @VoidCatz A modal dialog is one that remains on top of the main window of an app until the user dismisses it. This is different than a *modal* dialog which means that the user can switch back and forth and still interact with the main window.

Comment: I want to create a dialog that can be accessed by a static method just like a JOptionPane. I don't want to create an instance of JDialogTest anywhere else but inside of the static getInput() method. Thats why the constructor is private.

Comment: @VoidCatz: if you want something to behave like a JOptionPane, then **why not use a JOptionPane**? What is your rationale for discarding this useful tool?

Comment: @VoidCatz: and see edit to answer for static access. It's a lot simpler than you are trying.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Perhaps he is trying to learn how `JOptionPane` works? IMO, this is a good reason to ignore an existing tool.

Comment: @Code-Guru: perhaps, but he seems to be ignoring our request for clarification, so all we can do is guess. Perhaps he is ignorant as to the power of JOptionPanes, that they can hold entire GUI's within them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `while(true)` running in the same thread as the gui, is gonna to freeze your view, and is not the proper way you are using listeners. As your dialog is modal then the dialog has the flowcontrol.

Look at this SSCCE based in your example , with a few changes.

Example:

```
public class JDialogTest {

    private JDialog dialog;
    private JTextField textField;

private JDialogTest (String title, JFrame frame){
    dialog = new JDialog(frame, title, true);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    init();
}

public void setVisible(Boolean flag){
    dialog.setVisible(flag);
}

public static String getInput(String title, JFrame frame){
    JDialogTest input = new JDialogTest (title, frame);
    input.setVisible(true);
    String text = input.textField.getText();
    return text;
}

private void init(){

    textField = new JTextField();
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }

    });

    dialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));

    dialog.add(textField);
    dialog.add(okButton);
    dialog.pack();     
}

public static void main(String args []){
    String s = getInput("Dialog",null);
    System.out.println(s);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Again you wan to use a a modal JDialog and then query it for the text it holds once it has been dealt with. Since the dialog is modal, your calling application will know when the button has been pressed, if you make the dialog invisible within the button's ActionListener. This will then return control to the calling program. Your calling program can then query the dialog by calling a public method that you give it (here I called it `getText()` then then returns the String held by the dialog's JTextField.

For example, using your code...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JDialogTest extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
   // private boolean actionPerformed;
   private JButton okButton;
   private JTextField textField;

   private JDialogTest(String title, JFrame frame) {
      super(frame, title, true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
      init();
   }

   // public static String getInput(String title, JFrame frame) {
   // JDialogTest input = new JDialogTest(title, frame);
   // input.setVisible(true);
   //
   // while (true) {
   // if (input.actionPerformed) {
   // input.setVisible(false);
   // String text = input.textField.getText();
   // return text;
   // }
   // }
   // }

   private void init() {

      textField = new JTextField();
      okButton = new JButton("OK");
      okButton.addActionListener(this);

      // UGLY layout
      setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));

      add(textField);
      add(okButton);
      pack();
   }

   // I've added this method to allow outside methods to get text
   public String getText() {
      return textField.getText();
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      System.out.println("click");
      // actionPerformed = true;
      setVisible(false);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test JFrame");
      final JDialogTest jDialogTest = new JDialogTest("Dialog", frame);

      JButton button = new JButton(
            new AbstractAction("Press Me to Show Dialog") {
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  jDialogTest.setVisible(true);  // code is frozen here
                                          // until the dialog is no longer visible


                  // when code flow reaches here, we know that the dialog
                  // is no longer visible and 
                  // we now can query our JDialog to get its text
                  textField.setText(jDialogTest.getText());
               }
            });

      textField.setFocusable(false);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(button);
      panel.add(textField);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to display the dialog in a static way, change your `getInput` method to simply:

```
public static String getInput(String title, JFrame frame) {
  JDialogTest input = new JDialogTest(title, frame);

  input.setVisible(true);

  return input.getText();
}
```

---

Changes to calling code:

```
  final JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
  final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test JFrame");

  JButton button = new JButton(
        new AbstractAction("Press Me to Show Dialog") {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {                  
              String result = JDialogTest.getInput("Get Input", frame);
              textField.setText(result);
           }
        });
```

---

**Edit 2**

Note that JOptionPane works great:

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please enter input:", 
      "Get Input", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

---

**Edit 3**
You ask:

> The solution in the edit seems to work but what method should I use in the action listener to close the JDialog and return the text?

The dialog button's ActionListener will make the dialog invisible by either calling `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()`. See my code above or nachokk's code for examples.

Comment: I appreciate your answer very much, but what I was looking for was a static method that actually returns the input.

Comment: @VoidCatz see his edits, or my answer :) . The secret is that the modal dialog takes the control until it's dispose or setVisible(false). +1 very good as always hovercraft

Comment: The solution in the edit seems to work but what method should I use in   the action listener to close the JDialog and return the text?

Comment: @VoidCatz: the JDialog's JButton's ActionListener should close the dialog. See my code or nachokk's.

Comment: @VoidCatz in actionPerformed you don't return the text, in `actionPerformed` you only `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()` then the static method `getInput` continue execution , you request `dialog.textfield.getText()` and you return that, as show in example by hovercraft

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution. Take special note of the changes to the `JDialogTest` constructor, `getInput()` and `actionPerformed()`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JDialogTest extends JDialog implements ActionListener{
    private JButton okButton;
    private JTextField textField;

    private JDialogTest(String title, JFrame frame){
        super(frame, title, true);
        this.setModal(true);                   // Set the dialog as modal
        setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        init();
    }

    public static String getInput(String title, JFrame frame){
        JDialogTest input = new JDialogTest(title, frame);
        input.setVisible(true);
        return input.textField.getText();       // If this is executed, the dialog box has closed
    }

    private void init(){

        textField = new JTextField();
        okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(this);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));

        add(textField);
        add(okButton);
        pack();     
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("click");
        setVisible(false);             // Close the modal dialog box  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(JDialogTest.getInput("Test", null));
    }
}
```